# Slider stops loading pictures on a different page

Tags: wordpress, slider

I am building this site - http://www.bellated.us.lt/.

The problem is that the slider stops loading pictures for all other pages except for the main one. To see the problem you just have to press on any link from the menu. It is a wordpress system and all the code is added to the header.php. In fact, this file should be loaded properly always, not only for the main one.

Actually, I have no idea on how to solve this, so if you have any suggestions - please share.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post all relevant code here. If the site goes down it's no good use for anybody.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of network errors, like the following, on your page.

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://bellated.us.lt/js/lightbox.js"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://bellated.us.lt/sample-page/slider1.jpg"
```

So probably your issue is caused by a path error, where you are referencing your files with incorrect relative paths. If so, these might help:

```
<?php get_stylesheet_uri() ?>
<?php get_template_directory_uri(); ?>
```

See:

- [get_stylesheet_uri](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_uri)
- [get template directory uri](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri)